# The image files is uploaded successfully to the folder but file name is not saved in database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter

View Page input form. I was trying to upload a product with product images and complete the full crud operation about images and product details. This is the form for product details and image upload.

```
  <form action="" method="post" id="product_form">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Subcategory</label>
      <select class="form-control input-lg" id="select_subcategory">
        <option value="">Choose Subcategory</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
      </select>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Product Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="product_title" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Upload Images</label>
          <input class="form-control input-lg" type="file" id="prod_img" name="prod_img[]" 
          multiple="multiple">                              
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Brand</label>
                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="select_brand">
                  <option value="">Choose Brand</option>
                  <option>One</option>
                  <option>Two</option>      
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Color</label>
                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="product_color">
                   <option value="">Choose Color</option>
                   <option>White</option>
                   <option>Black</option>       
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Product Size</label>
                <select class="form-control input-lg" id="product_size">
                  <option value="">Select Size</option>
                  <option>Small</option>
                  <option>Medium</option>   
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="">Product Price</label>
               <input type="number" id="product_price" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Discounted Price</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="INR" class="form-control" id="prod_discount_price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="">Description</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_description">
             </div>
          </form>
          </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_product">Add Data</button>
            </div>
```

Ajax code on view page for snding data to the server.

```
   $(document).on("click", "#add_product", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var select_category = $("#select_category").val();
    var select_subcategory = $("#select_subcategory").val();
    var product_title = $("#product_title").val();
    var prod_img = $("#prod_img")[0].files;
    var select_brand = $("#select_brand").val();
    var product_color = $("#product_color").val();
    var product_size =  $("#product_size").val();
    var product_price = $("#product_price").val();
    var prod_discount_price = $("#prod_discount_price").val();
    var product_description = $("#product_description").val();

    if( select_category == "" || select_subcategory == "" || product_title == "" || select_brand == 
     "" || product_color == "" || product_size == "" || product_price == "" || prod_discount_price == 
     "" || product_description == "" )
    {
        alert("All fields are required");
    }
    else
    {
        var fd = new FormData();

        var ins = document.getElementById("prod_img").files.length;
        for(var i=0; i< ins; i++)
        {
            fd.append("prod_img[]", document.getElementById("prod_img").files[i]);
        }

        fd.append("select_category", select_category);
        fd.append("select_subcategory", select_subcategory);
        fd.append("product_title", product_title);
        fd.append("select_brand", select_brand);
        fd.append("product_color", product_color);
        fd.append("product_size", product_size);
        fd.append("product_price", product_price);
        fd.append("prod_discount_price", prod_discount_price);
        fd.append("product_description", product_description);

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>InsertProduct",
            type: "post",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                fetch();
                if(data.response == "success")
                {
                    $('#ProductModal').modal('hide');
                    $("#tbody").DataTable().destroy();
                    toastr["success"](data.message)
                }
                else
                {
                    toastr["error"](data.message)
                }
            }
        });
        $("#product_form")[0].reset();
       }
     });
```

Controller Code for uploading multiple image file and product details with session check. files are uploaded successfully in the folder. all details about product are successfully submitted to the database but the image section of database is empty. I was unable to send the image file name.

```
    public function InsertProduct()
    {
      if($this->session->userdata('email')=="" && $this->session->userdata('password')=="")
      {
           $this->load->view('Admin/index');
      }
      else if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
      {
           
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('select_category', 'Category', 'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('select_subcategory', ' Subcategory', 'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_title', 'Product Title', 'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('select_brand', 'Product Brand', 'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_color', 'Product Color', 'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_size', 'Product Size', 'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price', 'Product Price', 'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('prod_discount_price', 'Discount Price', 
            'required|trim');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_description', 'Product Description', 
          'required|trim');

           if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
           {
                $data = array('response' =>"error", 'message'=>validation_errors());
           }
           else
           {
                //$this->load->library('upload');
                $img = array();
                $no_of_images = count($_FILES['prod_img']['name']);
                if($no_of_images > 10)
                {
                     $data = array('response' =>"error", 'message'=>"10 Images allowed only");
                }
                else
                {
                     for($i = 0; $i < $no_of_images; $i++)
                     {
                          $_FILES['img_file']['name'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['name'][$i];
                          $_FILES['img_file']['type'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['type'][$i];
                          $_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['tmp_name'][$i];
                          $_FILES['img_file']['error'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['error'][$i];
                          $_FILES['img_file']['size'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['size'][$i];
                          
                          $config['upload_path'] = "./ProductImages/";
                          $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|jpeg|png"; 
                          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                          $this->upload->initialize($config);

                          if($this->upload->do_upload('img_file'))
                          {
                               $img_data = $this->upload->data();
                               $data[$i]['prod_img'][] = $img_data['file_name'];
                          }
                     }
                     if(!empty($data))
                     {
                          $data = $this->input->post();
                          if($this->adm->InsertProduct($data))
                          {
                               $data = array('response'=>"success", 'message'=>"Data updated 
                    successfully");
                          }
                          else
                          {
                               $data = array('response'=> "error", 'message'=> "failed");
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
           echo json_encode($data);
          }
       }

  Model Code for inserting data I have 

    public function InsertProduct($data)
    {
      return $this->db->insert('product',$data); 
    }
```

I have selected 4 image files to upload. Images are uploaded i get a successful message and i have
checked it in the mentioned folder. But image file name is not showing in the database. Help us
Thank you

Comment: https://ibb.co/JRbqbzh Database table images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the images name in product table as json_encode.

```
public function InsertProduct()
{
  if($this->session->userdata('email')=="" && $this->session->userdata('password')=="")
  {
       $this->load->view('Admin/index');
  }
  else if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
  {
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('select_category', 'Category', 'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('select_subcategory', ' Subcategory', 'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_title', 'Product Title', 'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('select_brand', 'Product Brand', 'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_color', 'Product Color', 'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_size', 'Product Size', 'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_price', 'Product Price', 'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('prod_discount_price', 'Discount Price',
        'required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_description', 'Product Description',
      'required|trim');
    
       if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {
            $data = array('response' =>"error", 'message'=>validation_errors());
       }
       else
       {
            //$this->load->library('upload');
            $img = array();
            $no_of_images = count($_FILES['prod_img']['name']);
            if($no_of_images > 10)
            {
                 $data = array('response' =>"error", 'message'=>"10 Images allowed only");
            }
            else
            {
                 for($i = 0; $i < $no_of_images; $i++)
                 {
                      $_FILES['img_file']['name'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['name'][$i];
                      $_FILES['img_file']['type'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['type'][$i];
                      $_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['tmp_name'][$i];
                      $_FILES['img_file']['error'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['error'][$i];
                      $_FILES['img_file']['size'] = $_FILES['prod_img']['size'][$i];
    
                      $config['upload_path'] = "./ProductImages/";
                      $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|jpeg|png";
                      $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                      $this->upload->initialize($config);
    
                      if($this->upload->do_upload('img_file'))
                      {
                           $img_data = $this->upload->data();
                           $img[] = $img_data['file_name'];
                      }
                 }
                 if(count($img) > 0){
                     $data['prod_img'] = json_encode($img);
                 }
    
                 if(!empty($data))
                 {
                      $data = $this->input->post();
                      if($this->adm->InsertProduct($data))
                      {
                           $data = array('response'=>"success", 'message'=>"Data updated 
                successfully");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                           $data = array('response'=> "error", 'message'=> "failed");
                      }
                 }
            }
       }
       echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
   
public function InsertProduct($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('product',$data);
}
```

Comment: I have tried according to your suggestions but again image is uploaded to the folder but not in database. i got error.  https://ibb.co/vhr344R

Comment: Can you print $data and see the output?

Comment: https://ibb.co/wWhzSkX yeah i got the output you can check i have printed the out put

Comment: Share the database schema for product table and images table.

Comment: If you want to save images name in product table then you have to save them as json encoded.

Comment: I have not created a separate table for images i just want to update these images in product table  https://ibb.co/wYTWHgt

Comment: So you want to save multiple images name in product table right?

Comment: Yes sir that's all

Comment: Okay you can save the images as json_encode. Let me change the code.

Comment: Updated my answer with the modified code.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now that i have uploaded those images successfully by your help i hope i won't get any error when i create a new view page for full description of a product with all these images.

Comment: If you have to get the images and want to display them then you have to json_decode them. Then you will get the images as array so you can loop through them.

Comment: I'll help you so let me know when you have to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your kind response.